# Using Holo-Light theme doesn't set the correct color to TextViews

Tags: android, android-listview, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-support-library

### Background

I'm adding a theme chooser of "Holo" and "Holo Light" (and maybe the dark action bar too) for my app "[**App Manager**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager)". For now I first try them out, via XML files.

### The problem

I'm using the support library by Google and try out the themes, yet no matter what attributes and themes I use, the textViews' color on my listView have the wrong color.

The listView contains 2 TextViews that are defined as such:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appLabelTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/isSystemAppImageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appIconImageView"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="label"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/appDescriptionTextView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appLabelTextView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/appLabelTextView"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/isSystemAppImageView"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="description"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

`Theme.AppCompat.Light` and `Theme.AppCompat`:

[image] [image]

Same happens when I do it all programmatically, and when I use ActionBarSherlock library.

Here's the themes configurations I use (tried ActionBarSherlock this time, but the same occurs for the normal support library) :

```
<style name="BaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light"></style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/BaseTheme">
    <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/normal_window_background</item>
</style>
```

and the manifest:

```
<application
    android:name="com.lb.app_manager.utils.App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:description="@string/app_description"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

The activity I've shown here doesn't have any code or XML that sets the theme to be different from what is written above.

### What I've tried

I've tried to check out the samples and saw no apparent difference between the XMLs and code. They work just fine...

Also, for some reason, the preferences activities are shown just fine.

Same issue exists on ActionBarShelock library.

### The question

How could it be ? what should be done to fix it?

Comment: Did you try without `android:textAppearance` attribute?

Comment: @shoerat yes. I really have no idea why it occurs. I've searched for anything I can think of : hidden styles, setting of colors programmatically,... really no idea why this occurs. currently, i've set the color per textView in order to deal with this weird situation. Also chose to use the cards-UI : https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lb.app_manager

Comment: Alright. I just checked above `TextView`s with zero modification to `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and [here is the screenshot](https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/-Kz_qNMRpHws/U0zJtYu2twI/AAAAAAAALis/K0tqDrxW0vo/w720-h1280-no/Screenshot_2014-04-15-14-52-26.png) from Galaxy Nexus (stock Android 4.3). No problems there, right? I suppose the problem is with particular device/emulator. What kind of device/emulator are you testing against?

Comment: @shoerat As I've mentioned, it works well when I use a sample code (or even a "hello world" project). I've tested my app on both emulators with 4.3 and 4.4 android versions and also on my device (Galaxy S3 I9300 with 4.3) . :(

Comment: Hmm.. checked your app on Play Store and I can see that you are using ABS themes. Any chances you might be mixing the AppCompat and Sherlock styles?

Comment: @shoerat I've tried them both, and both got me the same result. I use ABS for a totally different reason (settings activity can't have action bar on the support library). I will now publish the themes configurations I use. Maybe it will help.

Comment: I looks like the light theme is actually using the dark theme colors while the manifest theme is the light one, so I'm fairly certain the theme is set somewhere else and that theme is the dark theme. That actually makes sense because you'r using a theme chooser now ;-). But that also means you didn't post the code that _really_ sets the theme and that would probably be helpful to answer the question.

Comment: @EmanuelMoecklin that's because there is no code to set the theme. i've used only xml files for now, as I first wanted to check how each theme looks like. and I don't use the normal holo theme (which you called "dark") .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the cause to this problem.

It wasn't related to any XML or setting styles .

It was because of the LayourInflater of the adapter. I've created it via the application context instead of the one of the activity.

It also explains why my tests on sample projects worked fine, as I've checked the wrong stuff...

Comment: That saved my life for an old app I was refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

In Holo light theme and other Light themes we need to set Text color the only it will work..

```
  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/appLabelTextView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/isSystemAppImageView"
  android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/appIconImageView"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:textcolor="#000"
  android:text="label"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
  android:textStyle="bold"
  tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/appDescriptionTextView"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/appLabelTextView"
  android:layout_below="@+id/appLabelTextView"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/isSystemAppImageView"
  android:ellipsize="marquee"
  android:textcolor="#000"
  android:text="description"
  android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
  tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
```

Hope this will work.. Try this and let me know the result.

Comment: That's what I did in the end, but it's not the solution, as when I use the holo-light theme on sample projects and even on "hello world" project, I get the text color being changed automatically already to a black one. that's why I asked how could it be. :(

Comment: Automatically device will take the black color for Theme.Black and Theme.Light.. This depends on the app theme.. if you want to change the text color you have to change it manually.. i did the above modification and it works.. again i will check and update you..

Comment: you don't have to manually set it. just try making a "hello world" project (which uses either ABS or the support library) with the same xml files and you'll see it works just fine. Also, this solution won't work for me since I would also like to be able to let the user choose which theme to use.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the sample you provided with Theme.AppCompat and Theme.AppCompat.Light, and they both work correctly as expected, on both API level 10 and 18. Since you didn't provide full code, only snippets, it must be the case that there are additional bits of XML or code in your application somewhere that cause the problem.

A couple of things for you to check:

- Remove these entries from your AppTheme definition to make sure they are not interfering and causing the problem:

  ```
  <item name="android:listSeparatorTextViewStyle">@style/PreferenceListHeader</item>
  <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/normal_window_background</item>
  ```
- You may have different style definitions for different API levels. Check the contents of res/values-v11/styles.xml, res/values-v14/styles.xml etc. to make sure they are not interfering

Comment: Already tried removing the custom entries. Also tried using the default Holo-Light theme instead of using any kind of library, so the second suggestion won't help (I don't have special versions "values" folders anyway). I know it works fine on new projects as I've tested it myself and I still can't find out the reason for this. The other styles are configurations of a dialog theme (which isn't used on the problematic activity) and the "PreferenceListHeader" . "textAppearance" appears only in what I've mentioned, and setting a text color is only used on appWidgets and not on activities.